# Migration to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to upgrade my Magento 1 site to Magento 2. Here I am using this [tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html). Now my question is "how is it possible for me to know that my site is migrated successfully??"

Comment: what is the latest message? is you site working??

Comment: you can see the version name at the bottom of admin panel after logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the tools works fine then you can be assure that default data is being migrated but you must need to test the site and admin panel yourself to make sure everything works. You may find a couple of issues but can take a help from this article https://inbound.org/article/magento2-migration-guide-migrating-from-v1-x-to-2-x.

Answer (score 0):

**"how is it possible for me to know that my site is migrated successfully??**

1) Check for admin panel settings and data(products,orders,customers,cmspages,cms blocks)
2)Check magento version in migrated site.

Even though u migrate magento1.x to magento 2  with any tools you will be getting some error, based on your sites customization level.
So please go though the below like for solutions:

https://inbound.org/article/magento2-migration-guide-migrating-from-v1-x-to-2-x.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to ensure integrity and correctness of migration, you can **`create a replica of Magento 1.x store`** before starting migration to Magento 2.x. This will help you to match functionality and design manually after migration.

After creating replica, you need to clear logs and reports under var/log and var/report folder.

After migration has been completed, you should match design and functionality of replica website and migrated website.

Based on your website's customisation level, you may get some errors. To resolve those errors you may get help from google search and forums like:

https://inbound.org/article/magento2-migration-guide-migrating-from-v1-x-to-2-x

and

https://magento.stackexchange.com/